# Return Min/Abs of 3 numbers

Tags: java, math, integer, absolute, minimum

I'm working on an assignment where I'm supposed to return the smallest of 3 values (absolute values, as the program states). It worked perfectly when there were only 2 values that needed to be returned, but as soon as I added the 3rd one, it started saying "Cannot find symbol" at Math.min inside the method. :( I can't see what the problem is?

```
   public class Threeseven_RasmusDS
    {
    //Start of smallerAbsVal   
       public static int smallerAbsVal(int a, int b, int c) 
       {     

          int val = (Math.min(Math.abs(a), Math.abs(b), Math.abs(c)));    
          return val;
    }
    //End of smallerAbsVal

          public static void main(String[] args)
          {


          int val = smallerAbsVal(6, -9, -3);
          System.out.println(val);

    }
    //End of main

    }
    //End of class
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Math.min` lib method only accepts two parameters. If you want to do a `min` of three values, you need to do something like this:

```
Math.min( a, Math.min(b, c) );
```

In your context:

```
int val = Math.min(Math.abs(a), Math.min(Math.abs(b), Math.abs(c)));
```

Comment: or use a recursive method with an `int[]` as parameter (cleaner but it has limits)